# C# - How to simulate CD DRIVE?

Tags: c#, simulation

I would like to create a virtual cd drive,
i don't need too much, just a function to read bytes from the virtual drive.

Comment: I like the question but I would have no idea. Have you thought of using an ISO instead?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would involve writing the drivers for your virtual device... something you can't do with managed code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mount an ISO as a CD drive, check out [Virtual Clone Drive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html). If you want to read the ISO directly, you'll have to read up on the CD file system. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660